# Speed up Pandas on Multi-core machine

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that fits comfortably in memory. I do serval maps on the data frame, but each map is time-consuming due to the complexity of the call-back functions passed to map. 
I own a AWS C4 instance, which is 8-core and 16GB-RAM. I ran the python script on the machine and found that more than 80% of CPU time is idle. So, I think (correct me if I am not right) the python script is single-threaded and only consume 1 core.
Is there a way to speed up pandas on multi-core machine? 
Here is the snippet of the two time-consuming maps

```
 tfidf_features = df.apply(lambda r: compute_tfidf_features(r.q1_tfidf_bow, r.q2_tfidf_bow), axis=1)
 bin_features = df.apply(lambda r: compute_bin_features(r.q1_bin_bow, r.q2_bin_bow), axis=1)
```

Here is the `compute_tfidf_features` function

```
def compute_tfidf_features(sparse1, sparse2):
    nparray1 = sparse1.toarray()[0]
    nparray2 = sparse2.toarray()[0]

    features = pd.Series({
    'bow_tfidf_sum1': np.sum(sparse1),
    'bow_tfidf_sum2': np.sum(sparse2),
    'bow_tfidf_mean1': np.mean(sparse1),
    'bow_tfidf_mean2': np.mean(sparse2),
    'bow_tfidf_cosine': cosine(nparray1, nparray2),
    'bow_tfidf_jaccard': real_jaccard(nparray1, nparray2),
    'bow_tfidf_sym_kl_divergence': sym_kl_div(nparray1, nparray2),
    'bow_tfidf_pearson': pearsonr(nparray1, nparray2)[0]
    })

    return features
```

I am aware of a python library called dask, but it says that it’s not intended for a data frame that can comfortably fit in memory.

Comment: Related: [Status of parallelization of pandas.apply()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078880/status-of-parallelization-of-pandas-apply). Look there for some other Q's.

Answer (score 5):

Pandas does not support this. [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) arrays are mostly API compatible with Pandas and support parallel execution for `apply`.

You might also consider some bleeding edge solutions such as [this new tool](https://medium.com/@jmcarpenter2/swiftapply-automatically-efficient-pandas-apply-operations-50e1058909f9)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try modin.pandas?

`pip install modin`

`import modin.pandas as pd`

or multiprocesspandas ?

see here : https://pypi.org/project/multiprocesspandas/